# Deployment of MS Chart in ASP.net Application on Server

Tags: asp.net

I am using MS chart controls in my application but it's not working after deployment on Server.

How to deploy MSChart dll's on server or which setting is to be done in order to run my application correctly.

Looking for valuable solutions of yours,

Thanks in advance,
Supriya

Error :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first all your website error is unclear..either write exact error or elaborate it little more.
if it is regarding missing mschart assembly on deployed website then follow this.

when you publish you website then it will not include the mschart assembly. there are two dll files of mschart in your website bin directory named System.Web.UI.DataVisualization and System.Web.DataVisualization.dll as you see in image attached with post.
Copy these files to your published website bin directory after this it will work fine.

[image]

if you have not copied these files to your website local then you can find these in program files directory. you know the file names then you search them there..

secondly if there is some sort of error in web.config settings then follow this link to make them correct..
[ASP.NET Charts Tutorial](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/charts/ms-chart-controls-install.aspx)

Hope this will help you little bit..

Comment: k,I try this,thnx for the solution.

Comment: I tried it,but still getting error.Eroor500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.and if i remove chart control from page it's running well.

Comment: set <customErrors mode="Off"/> to see the exact error on your website.. change this tag in your web.config file.. then attach a screenshot if you not get the real issue of problem...

Comment: can you attach the screenshot of the error page??
run your application after setting up <customErros mode = "off"/> and take the screen shot of the error page and edit your post, then attach image with it.. hope this will clear the error much clear to me and others also..

Comment: it is showing correct.. the error details are below in stack trace.. it is just the error series details.. have you researched about the error details below this header section of page...

Comment: follow these links .. may be you will get the reason and let you solve your problem. your page have reason of your problem but you little unfamiliar with such problem. [link](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm)

[link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311766)
[link]http://ask-leo.com/whats_an_internal_server_error_and_how_do_i_fix_it.html